# How to use selected option is variable select list

Tags: javascript

For my code i need 2 selects, the first select is static (4 options that dont change) and the second select is dependant on what is selected in the first select.

Then depending on what is chosen in de the second list a function is executed.
i found some example code one W3schools that allow me to make the whole list thing: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_options3

So this works really well but now i dont know how to attach a function to the selected options in the second select since there is no where in the html to do something like an onchange.

Each option from the second select should have a function (in my code the selected option will display an image corresponding with the chosen option)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>   

<select id="car" onchange="ChangeCarList()"> 
  <option value="">-- Car --</option> 
  <option value="VO">Volvo</option> 
  <option value="VW">Volkswagen</option> 
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option> 
</select> 

<select id="carmodel"></select> 

<script>
var carsAndModels = {};
carsAndModels['VO'] = ['V70', 'XC60', 'XC90'];
carsAndModels['VW'] = ['Golf', 'Polo', 'Scirocco', 'Touareg'];
carsAndModels['BMW'] = ['M6', 'X5', 'Z3'];

function ChangeCarList() {
  var carList = document.getElementById("car");
  var modelList = document.getElementById("carmodel");
  var selCar = carList.options[carList.selectedIndex].value;
  while (modelList.options.length) {
    modelList.remove(0);
  }
  var cars = carsAndModels[selCar];
  if (cars) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
      var car = new Option(cars[i], i);
      modelList.options.add(car);
    }
  }
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried the addEventListener function.

Comment: How would that work, i can refer to the second select with its id but the options inside of the select dont because the are variable

Comment: You can attach event handler for the whole list, then this handler will check which option is selected using the 'selectedIndex' property of the Select and it will take the proper action.